# dropdown with add new item in a grid column

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I've already implemented a dropdown in a grid column according to this demo: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

I already did a test with this custom dropdown: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/addnewitem

I am wondering if it's possible to add this custom dropdown in a column of the grid to add a new category if the category is not found in the dropdown.

The column doesn't show in the column `Comment`.

I tried the following code without success, some tips of how to solve this?

EDIT 1: I tried the abinesh solution, and I think it is very close to solving this issue(http://dojo.telerik.com/OZIXOlUM). Still, the addNew function expects the widgetID. In the onclick of the add new button, the widgetID is passing nothing (see print screen). How did I get this ID? The script "noDataTemplate" is trying to get the id this way '#:instance.element[0].id#', but as I said, nothing returns.

[image: widgetID blank]

```js
<script id="noDataTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <div>
            No data found. Do you want to add new item - '#: instance.filterInput.val() #' ?
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button class="k-button" onclick="addNew('#: instance.element[0].id #', '#: instance.filterInput.val() #')">Add new item</button>
    </script>
    
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: categories
            });

            var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data : [ {
                    "Commen": "-",
                    "Confirmed": 1,
                    "Stat": 1
                },
                {
                    "Commen": "-",
                    "Confirmed": 1,
                    "Stat": 1
                },
                {
                    "Commen": "-",
                    "Confirmed": 1,
                    "Stat": 1
                },
                {
                    "Commen": "Some Comment",
                    "Confirmed": 1,
                    "Stat": 1
                }]
            });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource,
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    pageSizes: true,
                    buttonCount: 5
                },
                columns: [{
                        field: "Stat",
                        title: "Status"
                    }, {
                        field: "Confirmed",
                        title: "Confirmed",
                        template: " <input name='Confirmed' class='Confirmed' type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: Confirmed' #= Confirmed ? checked='checked' : '' #/>"
                    }, {
                        field: "Commen",
                        title: "Comment",
                        editor: commentCategoryEditor,
                        template:  "#=Commen#",                      
                        //template: "<input id='Commen'>",
                        width: 450,
                        nullable : true
                    }]
            }); 

        });

        var categories = [{
            "CategoryName": "-"
        },{
            "CategoryName": "Category 1"
        }, {
            "CategoryName": "Category 2"
        }];

        function commentCategoryEditor(container, options){
        $('<input name="Commen">')
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    filter: "startswith",
                    dataTextField: "CategoryName",
                    dataValueField: "CategoryID",
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    noDataTemplate: $("#noDataTemplate").html()
            });
        }

        function addNew(widgetId, value) {
            var widget = $("#" + widgetId).getKendoDropDownList();
            var dataSource = widget.dataSource;

            if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                dataSource.add({
                    CategoryID: 0,
                    CategoryName: value
                });
                dataSource.one("sync", function() {
                    widget.select(dataSource.view().length - 1);
                });
                dataSource.sync();
            }
        };     

    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Vat Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.silver.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/daterangepicker.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
        <div id="grid"></div>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample demo project that will help you add the category drop down:
[Dojo Telerik Link](https://dojo.telerik.com/uLAluxEM/2)

Sample Output of drop down list with add new category:
[image]

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Hi @Albinesh, thanks for your help. I see that your example dont have the "addNew" function, but helped me a lot to understand my issue. Unfortonatelly when i click "add new item" nothing happens. The problem now is that I'm already tried the addNew function but getting an error from the dataSource read : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSource' of undefined" I'm trying to fix this, but its not obvious to me. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @Researcher, Firstly, I showed you just the process of what you are trying to achieve and haven't included the part that needs to be handled on the server-side. However, you need to define an Id on the input tag($('<input id="categoryDDL" required name="' + options.field + '"/>')) while initializing the dropdown. Take a look at this sample dojo demo link: http://dojo.telerik.com/OZIXOlUM/7

Comment: thanks again for your comment, I started to use kendo a few weeks ago, and I'm a newbie in the tool. Your new suggestion worked. Just a question: If I want to add the newly added category one time and find that category in the next dropdown row, I will need to POST this new category to the server-side correct? This sync in the code only adds the data to the local dataSource, right? Again many thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: No Problem. Yes, if you needed the new data on the server-side you should and it is better because whenever users take a look at the same grid next time with category drop down the new data won't be there. This leads to data loss.